# how to serve static content in springboot 2.2.6?

Tags: java, spring-boot, static-content

I am newbie to Springboot and I am trying to display html page on its root(`localhost:8080`) path. To do so I googled and gone through -

1. [Spring Boot not serving static content](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24661289/spring-boot-not-serving-static-content)
2. https://spring.io/blog/2013/12/19/serving-static-web-content-with-spring-boot
3. [Spring Boot app not serving static content](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29172612/spring-boot-app-not-serving-static-content/45442056)
4. [Springboot does not serve static content](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60119885/springboot-does-not-serve-static-content)

Tried almost everything but none of them worked for me.

**Exact problem**

With out index.html file inside any of resources/(static/ or public/ or meta-inf/resources) works fine and show the list of some spring data rest. If I create an index.html file then it gives an error of `404` not found with out `@EnableWebMvc` annotation, if use `@EnableWebMvc` then it shows the list of Spring data rest apis.

Other than index.html file it show the list of Spring data api in root path, and url(`localhost:8080/test.html`) to other than index.html has same problem.

This problem has no effects by implementing `public class StaticResourceConfiguration implements WebMvcConfigurer` with this configuration to.

Comment: See this answer -https://stackoverflow.com/a/53698376/7849549

Comment: @Shubh  did not work for me, thank you for the link .. I missed that point

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### Starting with a [simple spring boot initializer](https://start.spring.io/#!type=maven-project&language=java&platformVersion=2.2.6.RELEASE&packaging=jar&jvmVersion=1.8&groupId=com.example&artifactId=demo&name=demo&description=Demo%20project%20for%20Spring%20Boot&packageName=com.example.demo&dependencies=web)

... we can place static (html) files into one of:

- (src/main/resources:)
- **static**
- **resources**
- **public**
- META-INF

  - **resources**

which results in the default (class path) locations, configured via the `spring.resources.static-locations` property.

These will be exposed through the value of `spring.mvc.static-path-pattern`-property ([ref](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/appendix-application-properties.html)), by default: `/**`.

So a static index.html file in one of the above mentioned folders, with default config, will be accessible at:

- [http:localhost:8080/](http://localhost:8080/) (due to "welcome file mapping" -> static mapping)
- and http://localhost:8080/index.html (due to the static mapping)

Accordingly: no problem with http://localhost:8080/test.html ...

---

Checkout [at github](https://github.com/xerx593/soq61393769/).

So this, at least answers the "question title" "how to serve static content in springboot 2.2.6?".

---

The order of `spring.resources.static-locations` appears (index.html preferred from META-INF/resources) also to be the "precedence" of static file locations (left-to-right, first match wins).

---

### When we add `@EnableWebMvc`

..."evertyhing gets broken" (context loads, but) only:

```
WARN ... o.s.web.servlet.PageNotFound             : No mapping for GET /
WARN ... o.s.web.servlet.PageNotFound             : No mapping for GET /index.html
WARN ... o.s.web.servlet.PageNotFound             : No mapping for GET /test.html
```

..please aslo consider this: [why spring-boot application doesn't require @EnableWebMvc](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51008382/592355)

With "non-default config", You would have to provide more details, to find a specific solution.

But for "newbie in Springboot": starting with an intializer and "the defaults" sounds optimal! From here on, you can re-fine your configuration based on a working one.

---

And if you *want/need* the `@EnableWebMvc` annotation for some reason, this will result in the "previous" behavior again/restore the (2.2.6) default static content handling:

```
@EnableWebMvc
@SpringBootApplication
public class DemoApplication implements WebMvcConfigurer {

    @Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
        registry
          .addResourceHandler("/**")
          .addResourceLocations("classpath:/META-INF/resources/", "classpath:/resources/", "classpath:/static/", "classpath:/public/");

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(DemoApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

(Assuming no conflicts with existing configuration/resource handlers)

Comment: Thanks for the tip, actually there was an issue with OpenApi jar file https://github.com/springdoc/springdoc-openapi/issues/361 (I was following old tutorial), Implementing new dependency solved the problem. Your statement about this should work helped alot and  started to remove dependency and check the error one by one.

Answer (score 0):

It's working for me

```
registry.addResourceHandler("//**").addResourceLocations("classpath:/static/");
```