# Couldn't access jpg file under resources/static folder

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc

I couldn't access the image under the `resources/static` folder. I'm using **Spring Boot version 2.112**.

I also tried adding **spring.resources.static-locations** in the properties file but still can't access the `.jpg` file from the `resources/static/image` folder. Any reason why?

```java
@Configuration
public class WebConfiguration extends WebMvcConfigurationSupport {
    
    @Override
    protected void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addResourceHandler("/**")
        .addResourceLocations("classpath:/static/", "classpath:/image/");
    }
```

Comment: it seems your resource is in `classpath:/static/image` folder.... can you add this to your configuration and test it?

Comment: I did that but it didn't work..

Answer (score 0):

Well, you may try https://stackoverflow.com/a/66361120/15215155. Most of time is about spring boot default security configuration.

**Edit:** Little edit here since it would be too much for comments.

Tackling the problem from another angle. Is there any specific feature you need from **WebMvcConfigurationSupport**?? If not, why not trying **WebSecurityConfigurer** for the resources handlers and **WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter** for the security config?.

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
public class MvcConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {

    @Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addResourceHandler("/css/**", "/js/**")
                .addResourceLocations("classpath:/static/", "classpath:/resources/static/");
        registry.addResourceHandler("/images/**").addResourceLocations("classpath:/static/images/");
    }
}


@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
   
 @Override
    public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
        web.ignoring()
        .antMatchers("/resources/**");
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.authorizeRequests()
        .antMatchers("/css/**", "/js/**", "/image/**"").permitAll()
    }
}
```

Comment: I added this line based on the spring.io blog                                              
 http.authorizeRequests()
.requestMatchers(PathRequest.toStaticResources().atCommonLocations()).permitAll();    to allow access to common static resource locations but I still can't access it.